# Python: How to remove / disable tooltip in PyScripter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyscripter

Does anyone know how to remove / disable tooltip in PyScripter?

[image]

Comment: ... just move the mouse away? Anyway, it seems like this is a question about the program you are using, not a question about programming itself. You might have better luck on https://superuser.com for this kind of thing.

Answer (score 0):

MENU -> TOOLS -> OPTIONS -> IDE OPTIONS -> EDITOR:

```
Show code hints -> FALSE

Show debugger hints -> FALSE
```

[image]